# BeautifulSoup: Problems with numbers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting some trouble with my code. The thing is that I'm extracting prices for a website and some of this prices includes the original price and the discounted one, and what i'm trying to get is only the discounted one. How do i fix it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&category1=998%2C996&category2=29"
category1 = ('998', '996')
category2 = '29'

params = {
    'sort_by': 'Price_ASC',
    'category1': ','.join(category1),
    'category2': category2,
}

response = requests.get(
    search_url,
    params=params
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
elms = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "title"})
prcs = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow"})
for elm in elms: 
    print(elm.text)
for prc in prcs:
    print(prc.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=next_sibling)

```
prcs = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow"})

for p in prcs:
    print(p.find('span').next_sibling.next)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [.contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children). `.contents` list all the children of the selected tag and from there select your desired tag, in your case the last children of the tag.

```
for prc in prcs:
    print(prc.contents[-1])
```